# convert json into array

Tags: php, jquery, json, handsontable

I have this script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(function($) {
    var newsList = $('.handsontable');


    function updateNews(){
        newsList.html("Loading…");
        $.ajax({
            url: "<?php echo $this->createUrl('data')?>",
            cache: false,

            success: function(data) {   

                 //alert(data);   

                newsList.html(JSON.parse(data));
            },
        });
    }

    updateNews();


});
```

which returns a valid json:

```
{
    "score": [
        {
            "player_fullname": "Alex",
            "game_id": "78",
            "player_id": "1"
        },
        {
            "player_fullname": "George",
            "game_id": "78",
            "player_id": "2"
        },
        {
            "player_fullname": "Nick",
            "game_id": "78",
            "player_id": "3"
        },
        {
            "player_fullname": "John",
            "game_id": "78",
            "player_id": "4"
        },
        {
            "player_fullname": "Steve",
            "game_id": "78",
            "player_id": "5"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want now to convert it into array. I tried JSON.parse(data), but it doesn't return anything. What am I doing wrong? Please help.

PS. I'm using Yii, this code is in a view, and I need to convert this data into array so that I can use it with handsontable api.

Comment: first console.log(data); and check what it returns string or object

Comment: it returns the json I mentioned above.

Comment: then you don't need to do this JSON.parse(data); direct use data its already JSON obj.

Answer (score 2):

First, add a `dataType` to your AJAX call, set it to `'json'` and it will automatically convert the data on re-entry. Now, simply set the data in your `success`

```
success: function(data) {
    var myArray = data.score;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@tymeJV is correct but if you REALLY need an array you can do this

```
var players = $.parseJSON(data);
```